# Expected Class delegate,enum,interfaceor or struct error

Tags: c#, enums

Hi Guys im really new to coding i dont understand what this error is could you explain or help me fix ths error im getting it on the public static byte im trying to make something for ps3 also i was trying to carry over something from another project i made but i keep getting this error

```
 namespace BO2
{
  internal class Typewriter
   {
    uint AllClientHUD = 1023;//Set A Certain Element To All Clients
    PS3API PS3 = new PS3API();
}
}

public static byte[] ToHexFloat(float Axis)
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Axis);
        Array.Reverse(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }
    public static void SetGlow(int elemIndex, int r1, int g1, int b1, int a1)
    {
        uint elem = OffsetsHUD.G_HudElems + ((Convert.ToUInt32(elemIndex)) * 0x88);
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + HElems.glowColor, RGBA(r1, g1, b1, a1));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    }

    public static void MoveShaderXY(uint index, float X, float Y)
    {
        PS3.Extension.WriteFloat(OffsetsHUD.G_HudElems + (index * 0x88) + HElems.X, X);
        PS3.Extension.WriteFloat(OffsetsHUD.G_HudElems + (index * 0x88) + HElems.Y, Y);
    }

    public static void MoveShaderY(uint index, float Y)
    {
        PS3.Extension.WriteFloat(OffsetsHUD.G_HudElems + (index * 0x88) + HElems.Y, Y);
    }
    public static void SetGlowText(int elemIndex, int client, string Text, short font, double fontScale, float x, float y, uint align, int sort, int R, int G, int B, int A, int R1, int G1, int B1, int A1)
    {
        uint elem = OffsetsHUD.G_HudElems + ((Convert.ToUInt32(elemIndex)) * 0x88);
        byte[] ClientID = ReverseBytes(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(client)));
        PS3.SetMemory(elem, new byte[0x88]);
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + HElems.type, ReverseBytes(BitConverter.GetBytes(1)));
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + 0x79, new byte[] { 0xFF });
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + HElems.FontSize, new byte[] { 0x3f, 0xc0 });
        PS3.Extension.WriteInt32(elem + HElems.text, G_LocalizedStringIndex(Text));
        PS3.Extension.WriteFloat(elem + HElems.FontSize, (float)fontScale);
        PS3.Extension.WriteInt16(elem + 0x70, font);
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + 0x70, new byte[] { 0x01 });
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + HElems.X, ToHexFloat(x));
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + HElems.Y, ToHexFloat(y));
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + HElems.color, RGBA(R, G, B, A));
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + HElems.color, RGBA(R1, G1, B1, A1));
        PS3.SetMemory(elem + HElems.clientOffset, ClientID);
        PS3.Extension.WriteByte(elem + HElems.flags, 1);
    }
    /*
            public static uint TOP_RIGHT = 168u;
            public static uint TOP_LEFT = 136u;
            public static uint TOP_CENTERED = 120u;
            public static uint BOTTOM_RIGHT = 170u;
            public static uint BOTTOM_LEFT = 138u;
            public static uint BOTTOM_CENTER = 154u;
            public static uint CENTER_MIDDLE = 146u;
            public static uint CENTER_LEFT = 130u;
            public static uint CENTER_RIGHT = 162u;

  }
```

Comment: Could you add the error you're getting to the post?

Comment: It's in the title...

Answer (score 1):

C# has no concept of "global" methods, so methods must be declared inside the body of a class or structure, not directly at the root of the file.

Comment: might sound dumb but howcould i go about fixing it

Comment: @AdamHeapsiMoD1998, if you have to ask that, you probably need to read a book or tutorial before you start to write code... I assume you just copied and pasted that code without understanding anything about it?

Comment: no i was following a tutorial and i just had no idea on how to fix this

Comment: Well, this doesn't look like code from a tutorial for beginners... this tutorial probably assumes that you understand what you're doing and know where to place the code. Perhaps you should start with something simpler.

Comment: true im going to leave it and research some more

Answer (score 0):

If  all your methods (ToHexFloar, SetGlow, etc...) are all related to the class TypeWriter, you should just write them right after the line PS3API PS3 = new PS3API();
that is to say inside that class.

```
namespace BO2
{
    internal class Typewriter
    {
        uint AllClientHUD = 1023;//Set A Certain Element To All Clients
        PS3API PS3 = new PS3API();

        public static byte[] ToHexFloat(float Axis)
        {
            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Axis);
            Array.Reverse(bytes);
            return bytes;
        }

        public static void SetGlow(int elemIndex, int r1, int g1, int b1, int a1)
        {
            uint elem = OffsetsHUD.G_HudElems + ((Convert.ToUInt32(elemIndex)) * 0x88);
            PS3.SetMemory(elem + HElems.glowColor, RGBA(r1, g1, b1, a1));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
        }

        ...

    }
}
```